# Symfony 4, find() an entity

Tags: php, symfony, controller, entity, symfony4

Thanks to the symfony doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object, i am able to use get/set methods from my entity called 'Produit'.

But when i call the method  setProduit() (from Paniers entity) Phpstorm say "expected App\Entity\Paniers, got Object" for the $produitSelected.

i don't know why phpstorm say that because i'm able to use methods, what's the problem ?
find() return an entity object, right ?

```
class PaniersController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
    * @Route("/paniers/add/{id}", name="paniers.add")
    */
    public function addPanier(Request $request, Environment $twig, RegistryInterface $doctrine, $id)
    {
        $produitSelected = $doctrine->getRepository(Produit::class)->find($id);
        if (!$produitSelected) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'Pas de produit trouvé pour l\' id : '.$id
            );
        }
        $lignePanier=$doctrine->getRepository(Paniers::class)->findOneBy(['produit' => $produitSelected, 'user' =>$this->getUser()]);
        if($produitSelected->getStock()>0){
            if ($lignePanier){
                $quantite =$lignePanier->getQuantite();
                $lignePanier->setQuantite($quantite+1);
            } else {
                $lignePanier = new Paniers();
                $lignePanier->setUser($this->getUser())
                ->setDateAjoutPanier(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d')))
                ->setQuantite(1)
                ->setProduit($produitSelected);
            }
            $doctrine->getManager()->persist($lignePanier);
            $produitSelected->setStock($produitSelected->getStock()-1);
            $doctrine->getManager()->persist($produitSelected);
            $doctrine->getManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PaniersRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="paniers")
 */
class Paniers
{

//...

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Produit")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="produit_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $produit;

     public function getProduit(): ?Produit
  {
      return $this->produit;
  }

  public function setProduit(?Produit $produit): self
  {
      $this->produit = $produit;
      return $this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Denis V's correct answer, I want to add that you could also modify your controller like this:

```php
public function addPanier(Request $request, Environment $twig, RegistryInterface $doctrine,ProduitRepository $produitRepository, $id)
        {
            $produitSelected = $produitRepostiory->find($id);
            //rest of the code
       }
```

This way phpstorm also knows the type of the returned object, as every returned object is type hinted in the corresponding repository.

Comment: Well yes, im using this when i want a custom method from my repository, maybe i should use that every time.
Same way for $lignePanier so ?

Comment: There are different ways to solve this specific problem :) Denis V mentioned one of them, I just wanted to add another. Surely - for every entity you wand to use, you could inject the corresponding repostiory into the controller method. This way phpstorm will always know what type the returned object has. Don't forget to typehint custom repository methods - if you create any.

Answer (score 3):

PhpStorm is apparently not that smart to understand that the actual type of the return value of `find($id)` in this case will be `Produit`. But you can help it:

```
/** @var Produit $produitSelected */
$produitSelected = $doctrine->getRepository(Produit::class)->find($id);
```

To make it working you should either use `Produit` with the full namespace or add the namespace directly within the type hint.

Of course this doesn't guarantee or ensure that the actual type will be `Produit`. So, if you make a mistake, PhpStorm will report the type incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to fix code :

Don't inject $id, you only need to typehint your entity: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter

Don't inject $doctrine, use  `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`

Don't inject $twig, use `return $this->render('...template', []);`

Use English, it is **always** the rule. Not only other people could help you but also because Symfony understands it and you will need that when you start using form collections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Inject repository and you will have autocomplete and spot errors easier. Use ```make:entity`` command and you will see what I think, hard to explain.

Comment: 1) Thanks for that
2-3) My teacher sended me samples with $doctrine/$twig so i started with bad habits but it's actually on my way
4) i have old forms (full php) but i will change that in the next hours so its nice to know